# Working with Angular as a Beginner - Retrieving Json-Data

Tags: angularjs

im trying to learn Angular but got stuck. Probably this is a very basic Problems but i cant find out whats wrong.

I have a laravel site with an API that grabs data from SQL. Works great when grabbing a whole list of citys. But i have a Problem getting a single city. Here is my approach:

**1.) Manually = WORKS!**

html

```
 <div ng-app="cityApp">

        <div ng-controller="singleCityController">

            <p>{{ city }}</p>

        </div>
```

script

```
 cityApp.controller('singleCityController', function($scope, $http){
       $http.get("http://localhost:8888/sqlapi/public/singleapi/5")
           .success(function(response) {$scope.city = response})
    });
```

In this approach I get a result:

```
[{"ID":5,"Name":"Amsterdam","CountryCode":"NLD","District":"Noord-Holland","Population":731200}]
```

**2. Automatic search-function = NO IDEA!**

Naturally, i dont want to keep the function manual. So im trying to read out an input-field to get the ID of the City. But i dont know how. I googled ng-model to ng-controller a few times but couldnt find the right thing.

my approach so far:

html:

```
<div ng-controller="getSingleCity">
    <p>CityID: <input type="text" ng-model="cityID"></p>
    <p>{{ singleCity }}</p>
</div>
```

script:

```
cityApp.controller('getSingleCity', function($scope, $http){
    $http.get("http://localhost:8888/sqlapi/public/singleapi/" ID???)
    .success(function(response) {$scope.singleCity = response})


});
```

How do i get the value from the ng-model to the ng-controller?

Thank you very much in advance. I know this must be very easy to solve but somehow i cant find the right piece of Information for this. So sorry to bother you with this kind of stuff but im stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can append $scope.cityID in the end of url as : url + $scope.cityID
so basically you have to :

```
<div ng-controller="getSingleCity">
<p>CityID: <input type="text" ng-model="cityID"></p><button ng-click="getCity()">Get City</button>
<p>{{ singleCity }}</p>
</div>
cityApp.controller('getSingleCity', function($scope, $http){
$scope.getCity = function(){
    $http.get("http://localhost:8888/sqlapi/public/singleapi/" + $scope.cidyID)
    .success(function(response) {$scope.singleCity = response})}
});
```

try something like this.

Comment: i tried:  $http.get("http://localhost:8888/sqlapi/public/singleapi/"+ $scope.cityID) but it does not work. Nothing happens...

Comment: You should first enter the id in input box and then use some button to trigger a function which will call that url.

Comment: on the button in html, with his code, you'd put `ng-click="getCity()"`